# PuTTYgen Error "Couldn't load private key (decryption check failed)

Tags: putty, openssh, winscp

I'm trying to load an OpenSSH private key that was created in `ssh-keygen` on Windows 10 22H2 to export it as a ppk for use in WinSCP 6.1 for SFTP authentication. When I try to do so in PuTTYgen 0.78, I get the following exception: "Couldn't load private key (decryption check failed)". When I tried to use the following command in WinSCP.exe to do the same task, same error occurs:

`.\WinSCP.exe /keygen "C:\Users\me\Downloads\SFTP\From IWOL\MyKey.key" /output=MyKey.ppk`

The key was generated using the following command:

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -b 384 -f "C:\Users\me\Downloads\SFTP\From IWOL\key" -Z aes256-cbc`

Is there a different utility I need to be able to convert this key to putty format? The key contents itself are in this format:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jYmMAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABDgKXkpwx
sHv1tZF27hWBhRAAAAEAAAAAEAAAAzAAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIGhdMAnTUjwRhJDQ
Mfgmxv8QEEw2R3wFsj8Yl2Yif402AAAAsA7B15BN0b0k/T+Zqwu5utB5o+TO/ISNq4wtbX
SOME MORE LINES TRIMMED FROM HERE
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of user error. I had generated two different keys and mixed up which passphrase I was using for which key. Many thanks to Martin for the quick response which prompted me to try generating keys from scratch which lead me to the cause.